# Google Analytics download link tracking

Tags: google-analytics, escaping

Is it necessary to URL escape the url in following js?

```
onclick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/internet/xyz/de/privatkunden.-Slot1-0113-File.File.FileRef.pdf/äü&.pdf');" href="/internet/xyz/de/privatkunden.-Slot1-0113-File.File.FileRef.pdf/äü&.pdf"
```

I JS-escaped it, before i write it on the page to make sure my JS will still work, but I'm not sure if URL escaping is required by google.

I couldn't find anything in the docs and on this board that said yes or no.

Thank you.

Comment: What change you did to the url?

Comment: the URL contains "äü&.pdf" as file name. Will GA handle those characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape your URL, the ga script do it for you.

`äü&.pdf` will be escaped as `%25C3%25A4%25C3%25BC%26.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works, but you should use this if you can:

Use the Async Snippet and then this:

```
<a onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/internet/xyz/de/privatkunden.-Slot1-0113-File.File.FileRef.pdf/äü&.pdf']);" href="/internet/xyz/de/privatkunden.-Slot1-0113-File.File.FileRef.pdf/äü&.pdf" target="_blank">pdf file name link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to track a download link is by using the event tracking.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

It's very similar to what you did - here is the code - _trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)

For example:

```
<a href="https://github.com/Soomla/AndroidStore/zipball/master" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'immediate_goals', 'android_code_download', 'Someone wants our ZIP !']);">Download <strong>ZIP File</strong></a>
```